# Parsing semicolon separated key value pairs into CSV file

Tags: bash, parsing, csv

I have a piece of data that is composed of semicolon separated key value pairs (a round 50 pairs) on the same line. The existence of all pairs is not necessary in each line.
Below is a sample of the data:

```
A=0.1; BB=2; CD=hi there; XZV=what's up; ...
A=-2; CD=hello; XZV=no; ...
```

I want to get a CSV file of this data, where the key becomes the field (column) name and the value becomes the row value of that particular line. Missing pairs should be replaced by default value or left blank.

In other words, I want my CSV to look like this:

```
A,BB,CD,XZV,....
0.1,2,"hi there","what's up",...
-2,0,"hello","no";...
```

The volume of my data is extremely large. What is the most efficient way to do this? Bash solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried any solution. I posted the question here to get some insights into how to approach the problem. I am not strong at bash, perl, ruby ... but I can do it by a c++ program. I just have a feeling that it can easily and elegantly be done in bash which is more appropriate to me.

Comment: Caesar, please read Elliott's comment about generality of your question again. Consider taking a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what kind of questions are welcome here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) .

Comment: Hint: use `string.split(;)` and then use a suitable regex on each element of the resulting array to get the value after the equals sign. Writing to CSV should be easy once you do that. :)

Comment: Does all lines have the same amount of columns with the same data fields?

Comment: "_Missing pairs should be replaced by default value or left blank._" When use which default value and when a blank field?

Comment: @hek2mgl Lines can have different combination of key value pairs. A line can have 0-50 key value pairs.

Comment: @Cyrus For missing pairs, let's leave it blank, no need for default value.

Comment: From the shell toolchain, awk is the best choice for the job. If you are fit in c++ and it's a repeating task, go for it.